# VPN back to home network for secure IP traffic?

Tags: vpn, ipsec

I'd like to set up a VPN running somewhere on my home network that would enable me to securely tunnel all Internet traffic through it from an untrusted network. That way, I could browse sensitive sites with a little less worry.

My top priorities are transparency and ease of setup.

I currently have a desktop PC (which could forseeably run a VM with VPN software), a Mac laptop, and an Apple Airport Extreme. Can I make do with what I already have, without purchasing a VPN-enabled router?

Answer (score 1):

[OpenVPN](http://openvpn.net/)

I'm not sure I clearly understand your approach to *securely tunnel all Internet traffic through it from an untrusted network*, but OpenVPN is the de facto open source VPN server/client software. The server comes with 2 users for free, and additional users are 5 dollars a piece.

There are a million how to's on how to tunnel all your traffic through OpenVPN, all you need to do is google for them and pick the one you like.

Also, the OpenVPN website is *very* helpful and has a lot of good info. They also have virtual machines you can download and try out - I run the ESXi version and it works out well.

[VMs](http://openvpn.net/index.php/access-server/download-openvpn-as-vm.html)

Comment: The OpenVPN virtual machine includes 2 free concurrent tunnels.  If you're just using it for your own system you'd only need one.  Therefore the virtual machine would be a great way to get started at no cost.